# How do I verify my installation

Tags: 16.04, software-installation

I was using dual boot system (windows and ubuntu).Then my ubuntu corrupted and after that I removed ubuntu and windows both and now I just installed ubuntu 16.04 again. But I am not sure that I did it correctly or not ?
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Explain what you did step by step. then only we can say for sure || but if your Ubuntu is working fine then mostly you did it correctly

Comment: What do you mean by doing it correctly? You want to make sure of what?

Comment: i want to make sure that windows is removed completely or not.

Answer (score 1):

Open "dash" and type "system testing".

The software this opens can be used to start tests on anything you can think of to test your hardware and configurations on. And then some.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this but i wanna make sure that i have only ubuntu in my laptop no any other partition of windows. Because when i open gparted then it shows a EFI system partition of 512 MB. and i am not sure what is that